# The specified table does not exist[entity]

Tags: c#, sql

I have spent hours trying to figure out why my database cannot find the table I have found numerous examples and none have seemed to help. I have created a separate class to handle the database operations so I can use it on multiple pages.
Here is the code

```
  [Table]
public class MatchItem
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull=false,IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int MatchID { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string MatchNumber { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string[] RedTeams { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string[] BlueTeams { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int RedFinal { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int BlueFinal{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Data context

```
public class MatchDataContext:DataContext
{
    public MatchDataContext(string connectionString) :
        base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public Table<MatchItem> Matches
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<MatchItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

I made a class so I could use it on multiple pages

```
public class MatchDBManager
{
    private static string connectionString = @"Data Source=isostore:/DB.sdf";

    public MatchDBManager()
    {

        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        using (MatchDataContext Mchdb = new MatchDataContext(connectionString))
        {

            if (Mchdb.DatabaseExists())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DB already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Mchdb.CreateDatabase();
                Console.WriteLine("DB created");
            }
        }
    }
    public void addMatchData(IList<MatchItem> data)
    {
        //this.clearData();
        //initialize();
        using (MatchDataContext Mchdb = new MatchDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            Mchdb.Matches.InsertAllOnSubmit(data);
            Mchdb.SubmitChanges();
        }

    }
    public IList<MatchItem> getTeamData(string teamNum)
    {
        IList<MatchItem> MatchList = null;
        using (MatchDataContext Mchdb = new MatchDataContext(connectionString))
        {

            IQueryable<MatchItem> mchQuery = from mch in Mchdb.Matches where (mch.RedTeams[0] == teamNum || mch.RedTeams[1] == teamNum || mch.RedTeams[2] == teamNum || mch.BlueTeams[0] == teamNum || mch.BlueTeams[1] == teamNum || mch.BlueTeams[2] == teamNum) select mch;
            MatchList = mchQuery.ToList();

        }
        return MatchList;
    }
    public IList<MatchItem> getEventData(string eventID)
    {
        IList<MatchItem> MatchList = null;
        using (MatchDataContext Mchdb = new MatchDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<MatchItem> mchQuery = from mch in Mchdb.Matches where mch.Event == eventID select mch;
            MatchList = mchQuery.ToList();
        }
        return MatchList;
    }
    private void clearData()
    {
        using (MatchDataContext Mchdb = new MatchDataContext(connectionString))
        {

            if (Mchdb.DatabaseExists())
            {
                Mchdb.DeleteDatabase();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the error The specified table does not exist[Match].

Added here is where I download

```
   public IList<MatchItem> ParseXML(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //List<string> save = new List<string>();
        List<MatchItem> MatchList= new List<MatchItem>();
        XElement matchData;
        matchData = XElement.Load(reader);
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        var matches = from item

                         in matchData.Elements("match")

                      select item;

        foreach (XElement eachmatch in matches)
        {
            MatchItem mch = new MatchItem();
           string Time = ((eachmatch.Element("pubdate").Value).ToString());
            mch.EventName = ((eachmatch.Element("event").Value).ToString());
            mch.MatchNumber = ((eachmatch.Element("mch").Value).ToString() + (eachmatch.Element("typ").Value).ToString());
            string[] RT = { eachmatch.Element("red1").Value.ToString(), eachmatch.Element("red2").Value.ToString(), eachmatch.Element("red3").Value.ToString() };
            string[] BT = { eachmatch.Element("blue1").Value.ToString(), eachmatch.Element("blue2").Value.ToString(), eachmatch.Element("blue3").Value.ToString() };
            string RF = ((eachmatch.Element("rfin").Value).ToString());
            string BF = ((eachmatch.Element("bfin").Value).ToString());
           // Time = Time.Substring(0, (Time.IndexOf("+") - 1));
            mch.Time = DateTime.Parse(Time);
            mch.RedTeams = RT;
            mch.BlueTeams = BT;
            mch.RedFinal = int.Parse(RF);
            mch.BlueFinal= int.Parse(BF);
            mch.MatchID = count;
            count += 1;


            MatchList.Add(mch);
        }
        return MatchList;

    }
```

This is where I call this method

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

 initializeDB();
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result));
            DownloadInfo di = new DownloadInfo();
            IList <MatchItem>data= di.ParseXML(reader);
            outputer(data);
            addData(data.ToList<MatchItem>());
        }
        else
        {
            IList<MatchItem> data = getTeamData(strMyTeam);
            outputer(data);
        }
}
```

**I ended up removing the DatabaseManager class and putting the functions in the main code**
Then I output them to the screen here

```
 public void outputer(IList<MatchItem> mch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mch.Count; i++)
        {
            Score sc = new Score();

            sc.Width = lsbData.Width;
            sc.Height = sc.Height;
            sc.Time = mch[i].Time.ToString();
            sc.Event = mch[i].EventName;
            sc.RT = mch[i].RedTeams[0] + "  " + mch[i].RedTeams[1] + "  " + mch[i].RedTeams[2];
            sc.BT = mch[i].BlueTeams[0] + "  " + mch[i].BlueTeams[1] + "  " + mch[i].BlueTeams[2];
            sc.RF = mch[i].RedFinal.ToString();
            sc.BF = mch[i].BlueFinal.ToString();
            lsbData.Items.Add(sc);
        }

    }
```

**note:score is a custom control that works(and worked) before the database code **

Comment: have you stepped through the code in debug?  where does it error out?  what are the values of the Variables?

Comment: It errors out when I try to add data to the table saying the table doesn't exist, ive tried just adding a single "Match" object to it however it errors on trying to read from the data base under getTeamData(stringgoeshere) and getEventData(stringgoeshere)

Comment: your select statement in getTeamData is not enclosed in Quotation marks, is that a typo here or in the code? looks like the same thing in getEventData.

Comment: WP7 or WP8? and have you tried adding the read-only parameter to the connection string?

Comment: Surprisingly you don't use quotations around the query you just leave it be, its wp7

Comment: read only didn't change anything

Comment: @Malachi it's a LINQ query on that line not a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you actually create a `Match` Object.

if you have you need to include that code in the question as well.  and if you haven't, that would explain why it doesn't exist.

**Addition**

in order to add `Match` Objects to a list you will have to create the objects first then add them to the list, I don't think you can create the whole list of objects before creating each individual object.

**more Additional Information**

the object still needs to be created before you can add items to it. that is what the error is telling you. you don't have the object to insert data into.

```
Match Table1 = new Match();
```

this creates a new `Match` object  which allows you to access the pieces of the object and insert data into the object like this

```
Table1.MatchNumber = 42
```

you can't add to something to a memory location until you set aside that memory location for that specific person and give it a name.

when you create that class you can add functions and all sorts of fun stuff to it, but you can't use any of it until you have created a `Match` Object.

you can't add something to a list that doesn't exist, you have to create the `Match` Object first, then add it to the list

Comment: I add an IList<Match> when I use the function     public void addMatchData(IList<Match> data)

Comment: I create an IList<Match> when I parse an xml file like: Match mch=new Match() and then add all properties from xml then add mch to the IList

Comment: The list works fine its when I try to get the old data or submit that new list

Comment: how does the list work when the objects inside the list aren't working?  your match object is a `Table` and not a `DB`. I still think that you need to Create the Table, Populate the Table, then Add the Table to the List.  not add data to the list object.  it seems like you might be trying to merge some steps together.

Comment: I think that you are trying to Create a Data Construct. the object still needs to be created before you can add items to it.  that is what the error is telling you.  you don't have the object to insert data into. `Match Table1 = new Match();`

Comment: Is this not right then? `foreach (XElement eachmatch in matches)
        {
            MatchItem mch = new MatchItem(); `

Comment: the only place where the `ParseXML` is called is inside your `InitializeDB()` Method if `e.Error == null`  and the XMLReader inside that references the `e.Result`  which is creating a reader for the error message?  that shouldn't be fed to your `ParseXML`  Maybe that if statement should say `if (e.Error != null)` ???

Comment: That's inside the we client download complete event, the e is the response from the download

Comment: sorry, I see now,  it's hard to debug when you don't have the code running on your machine.  so you are trying to build a Table based on the Response from the Download Complete Event?

Comment: Yep, I download the XML and then each XML element becomes a class of MatchItem, then store them into a List<MatchItem> which gets converted into an IList. I can display the data from the IList but I can't insert them into the database. It errors out on submitchanges() in the addData funtion

Comment: you are telling that addData to insert into and not create a table in the Database.  you probably want to use a Stored Procedure on the Database that will create and/or insert the information based and the parameters it is given.  you will have to add some more code to the application to do this as well.   at least that is what i am thinking with the information that I have to go off of.

Comment: But when you create the database and check to see if it exists in initializeDB() it should create the database as well as the table, addData was just made so that the insert on submit would be in a separate function

Comment: if you are inserting into a Table that is already there then you need to tell it what table it is inserting into, otherwise the table doesn't exist because you didn't tell it which table to insert into.

Comment: That's why you do Mchdb.Matches.insertonsubmit(data). Matches is the table

Comment: that is inserting it into the Table in the Application not in the Database

Comment: I made a simple program that inserts the time into a database and it works, all the same code -downloading an XML and with different classes. The only thing different is that my original program is in a panoramic application, and the program I just made isnt, so im thinking it might just be a problem when the original solution was created